# Color picker capture data

Tags: angular

I am implementing this color picker :
https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker

It has an HTML example :

```
<input [(colorPicker)]="color" 
       [style.background]="color"
       [cpOKButton]="true"
       (click)="saveColor(color)"
       (colorPickerChange)="onChangeColor(color)"
       [cpPresetColors]="['#fff', '#000', '#2889e9', '#e920e9', '#fff500', 'rgb(236,64,64)']"/>
```

It has an option [cpOKButton]="true" that alows to show or hide a button.
I don't understand the brackets meaning.

What I would like to achieve is when user clicks button, to pass the color through the function and add to an array.

Is there a way I can use the same function that is in the node_module?
If I look at the function file : https://github.com/Alberplz/angular2-color-picker/blob/master/src/color-picker.directive.ts
I see the user has a function  oKColor()

Here is also my component

```
export class ColorSelectorComponent  {

    private color: string = "rgb(236,64,64)";
    private color2: string = "rgb(236,64,64)";
    private color3: string = "rgb(236,64,64)";
    private color4: string = "rgb(236,64,64)";
    private color5: string = "rgba(45,208,45,1)";
    private color6: string = "#1973c0";
    private color7: string = "#f200bd";

    private arrayColors: any = {};
    private selectedColor: string = 'color';

    constructor(private cpService: ColorPickerService) {

        console.log(this.arrayColors);
        this.arrayColors['color'] = '#2883e9';
        this.arrayColors['color2'] = '#e920e9';
        this.arrayColors['color3'] = 'rgb(255,245,0)';
        this.arrayColors['color4'] = 'rgb(236,64,64)';
        this.arrayColors['color5'] = 'rgba(45,208,45,1)';
    }
   onChangeColor(color: string) {
        console.log(color);
    }

    addColor(event){
        console.log(event);
    }

    saveColor(a) {
    console.log(a);
        }

}
```

[image]

Comment: What do those `console.log` tell you when debugging?

Comment: nothing empty. it say's undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `cpToggleChange` event when we can check whether the dialog is open or not. If so then we can override `oKColor` method after `DialogComponent` is initialized.
It might look like this:

**view**

```
<input ... (cpToggleChange)="toggle($event)"/>
```

**component**

```
@ViewChild(ColorPickerDirective) colorPicker: ColorPickerDirective;

saveColor() {
  this.colors.push(this.color);
}

dialog: any;

toggle(value) {
  if(value && !this.dialog) {
    this.dialog = (this.colorPicker as any).dialog;
    const originOkClick = this.dialog.oKColor;
    const that = this; // it's required in this case
    this.dialog.oKColor = function() { // monkey patching okColor methos
      that.saveColor();
      return originOkClick.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if(this.dialog) {
    this.dialog = null;
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/hYLuiyyBqRJ1WA8cVk4A?p=preview)**

Comment: is there a way to pull out the OK button? So I can have a OK button outside the colorpicker input. As I don't want to have in the toggle display.

Comment: What is the problem with it? You have two-way binding for color and you can always read it whenever you want

Comment: i would like to have an OK button in a different place of the view.  Here is what I trying to achieve:
1)  display an input field with OK button
2) below input field display separately the colorpicker not position absolute.
when  user changes the color in the color picker, data gets passed to the input field and user can click confirm with the OK button.

Comment: I added a picture the question on how I am trying to layout.

Comment: I prevent closing color picker by calling `removeEventListener('mousedown`

Comment: you launching <color-picker> inside the <div class="color-picker-wrapper"> 
I am trying to get it out so the HTML markup would be 
<div class="top-part">
<input> <button >OK</button>
</div>
<div  class="color-picke-inlineBlock">
<color-picker>
</div>

Comment: see on http://alberplz.github.io/angular2-color-picker/examples/index.html in "Show the dialog permanently:"  they have a property [cpType]="'fixed'", and thought I can create the same span with the [cpType]="'fixed'" that will bind to the input , but I get error : "Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'cpType' since it isn't a known property of 'span'. (\"
           (cpToggleChange)=\"toggle($event)\"
           [cpToggle]=\"true\"
           [ERROR ->][cpType]=\"'fixed'\" ></span>. so Not clear what I am doing wrong

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/hhguS7jvA2cDpr3F0UpW?p=preview  You need to use `cpDialogDisplay`

Comment: Create plunker where you can show desired markup with OK button. I will try to help

Comment: Sorry @Yurzui. I should have done that from start. Here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/KADCoibbGL4NiZpjkFKn?p=preview

Comment: look like there is an error somewhere, as the colors array is not working. If you click OK it does not add the color to the COLORS array,  as the colors should show in the class="color-list" div.

Comment: Aa looks like you removed your previous functions that you created. so that why confirm etc does not work? are you still working on the plunker?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem with confirm. https://plnkr.co/edit/OsuTnBcuDv1jF6KILga0?p=preview

Comment: the plunker did not render properly. Now it does, everything perfect. Thank you Yurzui.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code (I change the parameter `color` to `$event`):

```
<input [(colorPicker)]="color" 
       [style.background]="color"
       [cpOKButton]="true"
       (click)="saveColor($event)"
       (colorPickerChange)="onChangeColor($event)"
       [cpPresetColors]="['#fff', '#000', '#2889e9', '#e920e9', '#fff500', 'rgb(236,64,64)']"/>
```

Comment: I tried and didn't work. I get this error in both results: 
EXCEPTION: Error in ./ColorSelectorComponent class ColorSelectorComponent - inline template:48:0 caused by: self.context.onClick is not a function

Comment: The function in the node_module, If I locate the file I can see there is  onClick() {) , and  I tested by adding an alert inside and it worked, but I don't want to update the node_module, incase I want to update it I will lose my changes. So trying to figure to access the function from my component.

Comment: Can you create a plnkr?